# Android Visualizer Stereo Capture

Tags: java, android, audio, visualizer

I'd like to use the Visualizer class to capture system wide audio in a specific format.  (44.1khz, 16 bits, Stereo)

I can't figure out how to request a certain format be returned to me.  I can get a hack to work in gingerbread and earlier to return audio formatted in 16 bits, but still no stereo.  Any ideas StackOverflow?

Comment: I've gotten it to capture audio, just not stereo, 16 bit audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Visualizer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) says:

> It is not an audio recording interface and only returns partial and low quality audio content.

and

> Two types of representation of audio content can be captured:
>
> - Waveform data: consecutive **8-bit (unsigned) mono** samples by using the getWaveForm(byte[]) method
>
>   Frequency data: 8-bit magnitude FFT by using the getFft(byte[]) method

Without modifying Android itself so that you can get hold of e.g. the Visualizer's input buffer I don't see how you could get data with a higher sampling rate / higher number of channels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael.  You know if there's a way to do this using NDK?  And just an FYI to you or anyone reading this here, MediaRecorder.snoop returns PCM format: 16 bit, mono, 44.1khz audio.  Visualizer returns: 8 bit, mono, 44.1khz samples.